# Как определить какая именно кнопка была нажата?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Если компонент каталога, модуль товара и что-то отдалённо напоминающие корзину покупок. Модуль товара — хранить список всех товаров, а модуль заказа — Id купленного товара и количество. Как определить что кнопка "Купить" конкретного товара была нажата, вывести об этом сообщение и сделать кнопку недействительной (disabled)? За любые замечания по коду огромнейший плюс в карму, спасибо!

**Catalog.vue**

```
<template>
    <b-row>
        <b-col sm="6" lg="4" xl="3" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
            <div class="image" v-lazy:background-image="product.image">
                Видно если нажали "Купить".
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <p class="mb-0">{{product.name}}</p>
                    <p class="mb-0">{{product.price}} грн.</p>
                </div>
                <b-button class="align-self-center" variant="outline-dark" @click="buyProduct(product.id)">Купить</b-button>
            </div>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
</template>

<script>
    import { BRow, BCol, BButton } from 'bootstrap-vue'
    import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        components: {
            BRow,
            BCol,
            BButton
        },
        computed: mapState({
            products: state => state.product.all
        }),
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('order', ['buyProduct'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

**product.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    strict: true,

    state: {
        page: 1,
        all: []
    },

    mutations: {
        incrementPage: (state) => {
            state.page++
        },
        addToAllProducts: (state, products) => {
            state.all.push(...products)
        }
    },

    actions: {
        getFourProducts: (context, $state) => {
            axios.get('http://api.local/api/products', {
                params: {
                    page: context.state.page
                },
            }).then(({ data }) => {
                if (data.data.length) {
                    context.commit('incrementPage')
                    context.commit('addToAllProducts', data.data)
                    $state.loaded()
                } else {
                    $state.complete()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**order.js**

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    strict: true,

    state: {
        all: []
    },

    mutations: {
        addToOrder(state, id) {
            state.all.push({
                id,
                quantity: 1
            })
        }
    },

    actions: {
        buyProduct(context, id) {
            context.commit('addToOrder', id)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю этого достаточно. Не проверил, т.к. нужно песочницу собирать, а вы своей не предоставили. Обратите внимание на метод `checkOrder(product.id)`, который я добавил.

```
<template>
    <b-row>
        <b-col sm="6" lg="4" xl="3" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
            <div class="image" v-if="checkOrder(product.id)" v-lazy:background-image="product.image">
                Видно если нажали "Купить".
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <p class="mb-0">{{product.name}}</p>
                    <p class="mb-0">{{product.price}} грн.</p>
                </div>
                <b-button class="align-self-center" variant="outline-dark" :disabled="checkOrder(product.id)" @click="buyProduct(product.id)">Купить</b-button>
            </div>
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
</template>

<script>
    import { BRow, BCol, BButton } from 'bootstrap-vue'
    import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        components: {
            BRow,
            BCol,
            BButton
        },
        computed: mapState({
            products: state => state.product.all,
            orderProducts: state => state.order.all
        }),
        methods: {
            ...mapActions('order', ['buyProduct']),
            checkOrder(id) {
              return this.orderProducts.some(p => p.id == id);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```